# Issue on accessing inherited members from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, montecarlo

I have a few issues with my the following classes . When I create an object of type "MonteCarloSingleAsset" and I apply to it the method "GetPrice()", I get this:

copy\pricinglib\montecarlosingleasset.h(81): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'MonteCarlo::stepsNumber'

copy\pricinglib\montecarlosingleasset.h(85): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'MonteCarlo::N'

copy\pricinglib\montecarlosingleasset.h(85): error C3867: 'MonteCarlo::N': function call missing argument list; use '&MonteCarlo::N' to create a pointer to member

Thanks in advance for your help.

In MonteCarlo.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MonteCarlo
{
   public:
        virtual ~MonteCarlo(){};

        MonteCarlo(unsigned long& _N,   unsigned long& _stepsNumber );

   protected:     
          T GetDiscountFactor(const double& r, const double& T);

          unsigned long N;  // num of sim
          unsigned long stepsNumber;  // steps for sde discretisation
        ;
 };

 template<typename T>
 T MonteCarlo<T> :: GetDiscountFactor(const double& r, const double& T) 
 {
    return exp(-r*T);
 }

 template<typename T>
 MonteCarlo<T> :: MonteCarlo(unsigned long& _N,   unsigned long& _stepsNumber)
 {
     N = _N;
     stepsNumber = _stepsNumber;
 }
```

In MonteCarloSingleAsset.h

```
#include "MonteCarlo.h"


template<typename T, char R>   
class MonteCarloSingleAsset
{
      public:


        T GetPrice(SingleAssetOption& option);

        MonteCarloSingleAsset(const unsigned long& _N, 
                             const string& SDEType,
                              const string& SDESimulType,
                               const unsigned long& _stepsNumber = 25);

        virtual ~MonteCarloSingleAsset(){};

      protected:
           string SDEType, SDESimulType; 


};

template<typename T, char R>
MonteCarloSingleAsset<T,R> :: MonteCarloSingleAsset(const unsigned long& _N, 
                                         //  const string& _randType, 
                                                const string& _SDEType,
                                                const string& _SDESimulType,
                                                const unsigned long& _stepsNumber)      

  :  MonteCarlo<T>(_N, _stepsNumber)

  {
     SDEType = _SDEType;  // GBM, VAS, MER, CIR
     SDESimulType = _SDESimulType; // EUMAR, MIL = milstein
  }


template<typename T, char R>
T MonteCarloSingleAsset<T,R> ::  GetPrice(SingleAssetOption& option)
{


    T sum = 0.0;
    T payOff = 0.0;
    vector<T> path;
    vector<T> rand;
    Interval<T> range(0.0, option.GetT());

    BasicMethod<T> randGen(1);

    GBMSDE<T> sde(option.GetS(), range, option.GetR() , option.GetVol());



    EulerMaruyamaScheme simulator(MonteCarlo<T> :: stepsNumber);


     for (unsigned long i = 1; i <= MonteCarlo<T> :: N ; i++)
     {
        rand = randGen.GetRandomVector( MonteCarlo<T> :: stepsNumber);
        path = simulator.SimPath(sde,rand);
        payOff = option.GetPayOff(path); 
        sum += payOff;
     }    

      double disFact = MonteCarlo<T> :: GetDiscountFactor(option.GetR(), option.GetT());

      return (1 / MonteCarlo<T> :: N )*disFact*sum; 
 }
```

Comment: For starters, where is the inheritance?

Comment: To access MonteCarlo<T>::stepsNumber the stepsNumber must be defined as static (    static unsigned long stepsNumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "illegal reference to non-static member" tells you that you're trying to access a member variable or function as if it was static.

For example, with `MonteCarlo<T> :: stepsNumber` the `MonteCarlo<T>` part is just the name of a type, not an actual instance of it.

Either you need to change your MonteCarlo class to have static members.

Or else you need to create instances. For example:

```
MonteCarlo<T> m;
m.stepsNumber;
```

Or perhaps you meant for `MonteCarloSingleAsset` to derive from `MonteCarlo`, which would change the situation significantly. However that's not what your code is currently doing.